# Guild wars 2 crashes when entering world

Tags: guild-wars-2

When I select my character, and hit play the game crashes. A box with the crash report shows up. The game doesn't close, it just says explosive intellect (I think it's the starting area). My drivers are up to date.

My PC specification is as follows;

- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 675M
- CPU: intel i7.3638QM
- RAM: 8GB (4GB*2)

The crash report is as follows;

```
*--> Crash <--*
Assertion: hdr->signature == PACKFILE_SIGNATURE 
File: ..\..\..\Services\Packfile\Packfile.cpp(1819)
App: Gw2.exe 
Pid: 11084
Cmdline: 
BaseAddr: 00400000
ProgramId: 101
Build: 28611
When: 2014-01-20T16:05:00Z 2014-01-20T17:05:00+01:00
Uptime:   0 days  0:00:51
Flags: 0

*--> System <--*
Name: SUPERGAMER
IpAddr: 192.168.1.15 25.107.100.238
Processors: 8 [GenuineIntel:6:10:9]
OSVersion: Windows 6.1 (64 bit)

*--> System Memory <--*
Physical:  4643MB/ 8088MB  57%
Paged:    11602MB/16175MB  71%
Virtual:   2598MB/ 4095MB  63%
Load: 42%
CommitTotal:   4573MB
CommitLimit:  16175MB
CommitPeak:    5115MB
SystemCache:   4568MB
HandleCount:  34723
ProcessCount:   110
ThreadCount:   1809

*--> Process Memory <--*
Private:         1056MB
WorkingSet:       359MB
PeakWorkingSet:   364MB
PageFaults:    330694

[DbgHelp.dll is C:\windows\system32\dbghelp.dll]
[DbgHelp.dll version 6.1.7601.17514 (64/32-bit compatible)]

*--> SerialLoader0 Thread 0x2850 <--*

*--> Trace <--*
Pc:0091a82c Fr:3b90fe8c Rt:0091aaba Arg:00000002 214ad9fc 2144cdd0 00000000 
Pc:0091aaba Fr:3b90feb4 Rt:0091b828 Arg:2144cdd0 00000000 00000000 0000000d 
Pc:0091b828 Fr:3b90fed0 Rt:008ec481 Arg:2144cdd0 0000000d 00000044 017a9c78 
Pc:008ec481 Fr:3b90feec Rt:0091712a Arg:2144cdd0 00060c2c 182e0a90 008ebf62 
Pc:0091712a Fr:3b90ff14 Rt:009490ba Arg:00000000 0f683b60 03a56038 00000002 
Pc:009490ba Fr:3b90ff30 Rt:006edfcf Arg:00000000 03a56038 00000000 3b90ff7c 
Pc:006edfcf Fr:3b90ff44 Rt:0096133d Arg:0f683b60 70375a14 00000000 03a56038 
Pc:0096133d Fr:3b90ff7c Rt:009613e5 Arg:00000000 3b90ff94 768c336a 03a56038 
Pc:009613e5 Fr:3b90ff88 Rt:768c336a Arg:03a56038 3b90ffd4 777e9f72 03a56038 
Pc:768c336a Fr:3b90ff94 Rt:777e9f72 Arg:03a56038 486510e8 00000000 00000000 
Pc:777e9f72 Fr:3b90ffd4 Rt:777e9f45 Arg:00961363 03a56038 00000000 00000000 
Pc:777e9f45 Fr:3b90ffec Rt:00000000 Arg:00961363 03a56038 00000000 00000000 

*--> Thread registers <--*
eax=3b90fa50 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000044 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=0091a82c esp=3b90fe64 ebp=3b90fe8c
cs=0023 ss=002b ds=002b es=002b fs=0053 gs=002b efl=00000246

eax-32 3B90FA30  3b90faa0 006f3c55 00000000 3b90faa0 
eax-16 3B90FA40  7686c40d 3b90faa0 7686c41f 3b90fa50 
eax +0 3B90FA50  80000003 00000000 00000000 7686c41f 
eax+16 3B90FA60  00000002 00000002 10fed630 00000280 
eax+32 3B90FA70  76871ac0 00000044 3b90fdd0 3b90fb50 
eax+48 3B90FA80  3b90faa4 009650ef 3b90fb50 00000000 

*--> Code <--*
0091A80C  5201e8fd 95ddffba 50460000 66391774 R.......PF..f9.t
0091A81C  14681b07 0000ba44 7b5201b9 28805201 .h.....D{R..(.R.
0091A82C  e8df95dd ff8b4708 8343100c 894318f6 ......G..C...C..
0091A83C  47020174 07814b14 00000080 f6470204 G..t..K......G..
0091A84C  0fb74f06 8d4c0ef4 894d10c7 45080000 ..O..L...M..E...
0091A85C  00007410 c7450801 000000eb 078da424 ..t..E.........$

*--> Stack <--*
3B90FE64  0091a831 0000071b 182e0ba0 00060c2c 1...........,...
3B90FE74  00000002 3b90fe98 0091a709 00000018 .......;........
3B90FE84  00000000 00000000 3b90feb4 0091aaba ...........;....
3B90FE94  00000002 214ad9fc 2144cdd0 00000000 ......J!..D!....
3B90FEA4  00000000 017a9c78 182e0a24 182e0ac4 ....x.z.$.......
3B90FEB4  3b90fed0 0091b828 2144cdd0 00000000 ...;(.....D!....
3B90FEC4  00000000 0000000d 00000044 3b90feec ........D......;
3B90FED4  008ec481 2144cdd0 0000000d 00000044 ......D!....D...
3B90FEE4  017a9c78 182e0a50 3b90ff14 0091712a x.z.P......;*q..
3B90FEF4  2144cdd0 00060c2c 182e0a90 008ebf62 ..D!,.......b...
3B90FF04  017a9cb0 017a9cb0 3b90ff30 70375a7c ..z...z.0..;|Z7p
3B90FF14  3b90ff30 009490ba 00000000 0f683b60 0..;........`;h.
3B90FF24  03a56038 00000002 0f683b64 3b90ff44 8`......d;h.D..;
3B90FF34  006edfcf 00000000 03a56038 00000000 ..n.....8`......
3B90FF44  3b90ff7c 0096133d 0f683b60 70375a14 |..;=...`;h..Z7p
3B90FF54  00000000 03a56038 03a56038 80000003 ....8`..8`......
3B90FF64  3b90ff50 3b90f498 3b90ffc4 009614a0 P..;...;...;....
3B90FF74  4acf69f8 00000000 3b90ff88 009613e5 .i.J.......;....
3B90FF84  00000000 3b90ff94 768c336a 03a56038 .......;j3.v8`..
3B90FF94  3b90ffd4 777e9f72 03a56038 486510e8 ...;r.~w8`....eH
3B90FFA4  00000000 00000000 03a56038 80000003 ........8`......
3B90FFB4  768e76c7 768e76c7 3b90ffa0 3b90f49c .v.v.v.v...;...;
3B90FFC4  ffffffff 778271f5 04882a6c 00000000 .....q.wl*......
3B90FFD4  3b90ffec 777e9f45 00961363 03a56038 ...;E.~wc...8`..
3B90FFE4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B90FFF4  00961363 03a56038 00000000 00000000 c...8`..........
3B910004  00000000 00251700 00000000 0024f900 ......%.......$.
3B910014  00000000 09e2fc6c 00000000 09e2fe60 ....l.......`...
3B910024  00000000 000001e0 00000000 aeb2dac5 ................
3B910034  000000af 473b8000 00000002 09e2fe4f ......;G....O...
3B910044  00000000 09e30040 00000000 000001e0 ....@...........
3B910054  00000000 aeb463a6 000000af 473b8000 .....c........;G
3B910064  00000002 09d9c091 00000000 00000000 ................
3B910074  00000000 000001e0 00000000 a72f38ab .............8/.
3B910084  000000af 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B910094  00000000 00000001 00000007 45504344 ............DCPE
3B9100A4  00000000 000000ce 00000000 000186a0 ................
3B9100B4  00000000 0042005c 00730061 004e0065 ....\.B.a.s.e.N.
3B9100C4  006d0061 00640065 0062004f 0065006a a.m.e.d.O.b.j.e.
3B9100D4  00740063 005c0073 00750041 00690064 c.t.s.\.A.u.d.i.
3B9100E4  0045006f 0067006e 006e0069 00440065 o.E.n.g.i.n.e.D.
3B9100F4  00700075 0069006c 00610063 00650074 u.p.l.i.c.a.t.e.
3B910104  00610048 0064006e 0065006c 00700041 H.a.n.d.l.e.A.p.
3B910114  00500069 0072006f 00320074 00300030 i.P.o.r.t.2.0.0.
3B910124  00350038 00380031 00380034 00000038 8.5.1.8.4.8.8...
3B910134  00000000 00000019 00000180 00000800 ................
3B910144  00002600 0002fffe 0000bb80 0002ee00 .&..............
3B910154  00100004 00100016 00000000 00000001 ................
3B910164  00100000 aa000080 719b3800 00000000 .........8.q....
3B910174  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B910184  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B910194  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B9101A4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B9101B4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B9101C4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B9101D4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B9101E4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B9101F4  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B910204  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B910214  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B910224  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B910234  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B910244  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................
3B910254  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................

*--> Error Logs <--*
VerifyAccess failed or denied access with 0x80070716 - 1

*--> DirectX Device Info <--*
VendorId    = 0x10de
DeviceId    = 0x1212
Version     = 9.18.0013.3221
Description = NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675M
Compat      = 0x00100800
VidMem      = 4046 MB
```

Please leave a comment if you need any further information.

Comment: Mind linking the crash report in pastebin? It will help if we know more about the issue. or does it ONLY say "Explosive Intellect"?

Comment: what does the crash report say?

Comment: in the game it only says explosive intellect... I'll link the crash report

Comment: i dont know how to put it in past bin, so i pasted it in the question :P

Comment: Windows 7 or 8?

Comment: windows 7 64 bit

Comment: I can tell you that it is a memory allocation issue, but it's very difficult to narrow it down to a specific cause. Are you using Overwolf?

Comment: nope im not using it

Comment: What happens if you make a character in another starting area? (other than asura)

Comment: i'll try, and report back
how do i select a new spawning area...

Comment: still crashes...

Comment: Does it still show the starting area when it crashes?

Comment: it never showed the starting area, it just said "explosive intellect" at the bottom off the screen, everything else is black (black screen with text)

Comment: Has it been a longe time since you played last and the character is in the crown pavilion (which isn't available anymore)? A few players reported that they still have charachters there and if they want to login onto that char their game crashes.

Answer (score 1):

`PackFile.cpp` contains code to deal with the packaged files in the `.dat`. The crash is due to an assertion in the code that a "signature" value in the header of one of the files matches the expected value (`PACKFILE_SIGNATURE`).

This generally suggests that your `.dat` is corrupted. You can try to launch the game with `-repair`, but as the code tries to repair issues when possible this is unlikely to work. You may need to delete (or move aside) the `.dat` and allow the client to redownload it.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like it could be another program running that's causing the issue. It could also be a registry issue with Windows 8. Accessing this memory location seems to be a common issue with upgrading to windows 8 from windows 7.

Try following what is done in this to solve your issue.
http://bit.ly/1kQG4MU

Comment: This seems to just be a guess, which means it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: well i have windows 7, and didnt upgrade to windows 8...